# Norm statement redundancy

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Here is the statement about norm
$\forall{x\in{V}:||x||\geq{0}\land{(||x||=0\implies{x=0})}} $
What is redundant compared to the norm axiom? ($V$ - just a vector space).

$x\ne{0}\implies{||x||>0}$

Comment: how about a statement regarding $\|0\|$

Comment: do you mean statement’s inequality strictness?